# How opinionated is magento2 frontend(JS)?

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, requirejs

I hope this question makes sense, there is a chance it doesn't.

I am looking into creating a custom checkout module for Magento2 and as a part of it i am evaluating JS frameworks. After evaluating some i wanted to try out AureliaIO and typescript. It uses system.js for module loading(magento2 uses requirejs) and after trying to include this for a while i realised there are some issues using these technologies side by side. I dont know if a framework like aurelia is the right choice but that is not what my question is about.

My thinking revolves around wheter magento2 designed to have me use the supplied utilities like knockout.js and require.js or to have the plathora of frontend tech available without breaking to much native goodies.

In other words, am i putting myself in a bad spot if i exclude require, knockout etc for this particular checkout page in favour of other frontend tech? How opinionated is magento2 frontend?